# Webapi with EntityFramework gives Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a Webapi project that runs fine when the database is local.  However when I run the code locally and connect to a sql server on the Network I get a list of errors.

It starts with

```
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
```

and the inner most exception is

```
Login failed for user '*********'
```

I believe that the credentials are good because the Entity Framework used the credentials to show me a list of possible tables and I can log in with Sql Management Studio. Also, when I debug, the LINQ results are correct.  They just are not returned by the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the problem in the end?

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by several things. First, make sure that your connection string is correct (have a closer look if you specify any port). Second, make sure that your SQL Server Browser service is running. For more information have a look at the this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/48105/sql-server-2008-remote-logins-fail-local-succeeds-remote-logins-enabled)

Comment: When I use the credentials in the Entity wizard, they connect just fine.  So I am fairly positive that the string it generated is correct.  When I debug, it queries the database and gets a result correctly.  It just throws that error as a response instead of the values.